# How can I add Expire headers to images?

Tags: plugins, cache

I'm trying to speed up my site a bit. How can I add Expire headers to images I upload? Must this be done with Apache configuration, or is there a setting or plugin to do the job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with Apache configuration, I have used this snippet in the past in .htaccess:

```
ExpiresActive On 
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month" 
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month" 
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
```

Can be set up with plugin as well. [W3 Total Cache](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/w3-total-cache/) (which I currently use) can do that among other things.

Overall this is not a huge performance factor. Modern browsers are smart enough about caching images even without expires set.